# How to see data buffer in the PowerBuilder 12.5 Debugger?

Tags: .net, debugging, powerbuilder, datastore, watch

As this option should be as new feature in PowerBuilder 12.5 .NET, but in Debugger I could not see any data in DataStore object. The object information shows in Debugger are only "base", "DataObject" and "FlowDirection", but nothing more. How to reach to see the data in DataStore object while debugging?

In previous PowerBuilder versions I was able to do that by calling of SaveAs() method in Watch and DataStore data was saved in local file. But now, this option does not work (only in source code) it returns ") expected".

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to **Unit Test your DataWindows**. You can test them by hand in the DataWindow Painter or you can write unit tests in PowerUnit. **You should not be wondering about the data in the DataWindow when you are in the Debugger**. If the code you're debugging is accessing the data you will see the values it is getting, the retrieval arguments, etc. If the code doesn't access the data why would you care what it is? As it happens I just got through modifying the SELECT in about 30 DataWindows due to a schema change and I'm having a wonderful time unit testing them, since nobody wrote tests for them before. Also, write your code so it is easier to debug. For example, get return values into variables instead of using them directly.

Comment: I should mention that our framework (PFC-based) has SaveAs>Excel and SaveAs>PDF built into the ancestor menu, an event in our mid-tier ancestor for u_dw for SaveAs, and code in our mid_tier ancestor of w_sheet that directs the event to the largest visible DataWindow if the last focused object isn't a DataWindow (this is mainly for reports). The save as uses the DataWindow's save as dialog, so you can make it any format you want. Because of this the data in a DataWindow is always just a couple of mouse clicks away.

Answer (score 0):

added additional paragraph on 11/2-12 - I ran across a pretty cool way to view buffer data while debugging, this would be most useful for datastores but should work fine for datawindow. Check out this site section [Save DataStore from Debugger](http://zuskin.com/pb_tricks.htm).

One workaround I commonly use is to **add code to the clicked event** of a **datawindow control** (ancestor is even better) and use the keydown function to determine of a pre-defined and obscure key combination has been pressed.  If it has then the **data should be saved to file**.

I like to create **hidden easter-egg features** for the most common types including one generic one that prompts the user for file type and name.

ctl+alt+**e** for Excel!

ctl+alt+**t** for Text!

ctl+alt+**c** for CSV!

ctrl+alt+**a** for Any (Prompted with SaveAs dialog)

So if the user holds **ctrl+alt+e** and **clicks anywhere on the dataobject** the following code will be triggered causing the data to be written to excel, and the excel file automatically opened. I often leave this functionality in production applications (sometimes I filter for my userid depending on how sensitive the data is) because it is a **GREAT production support tool**.  Our **QA department also loves the functionality** as they can document data easily and they can view all columns even those not shown.

```
long ll_handle
string ls_filename, ls_null, ls_dir

if keydown(KeyControl!) and keydown(KeyAlt!) then

    // set work variables to be used in save 
    SetNull(ls_null)

    // grab handle to MDI frame window for the ShellExecute function
    ll_handle = Handle(gwMdi)

    // construct the filename using dataobject and datetime  
    ls_dir = "c:\temp"
    ls_filename = ls_dir + '\debug_dataobject_' + this.dataobject + '_date_' + string(Today(),'mmddyyhhmmss') 

    // determine if we are saving excel, text, csv, or prompting for filetype
    if keydown(keye!) then
       ls_filename =+ '.xls'
       dw_1.SaveAs(ls_filename, Excel!,True!)
    elseif keydown(keyt!) then
       ls_filename =+ '.txt'
       dw_1.SaveAs(ls_filename, Text!,True!)
    elseif keydown(keyc!) then
       ls_filename =+ '.txt'
       dw_1.SaveAs(ls_filename, Csv!,True!)
    elseif keydown(keya!) then
       ls_filename =+ ''
       // empty string forces dialog open
       dw_1.SaveAs(ls_filename)
    end if

   // now automatically open the file using default program 
   // for the file type via Windows API function
   if fileexists(ls_filename) then
      gwMdi.ShellExecute(ll_handle, 'open', ls_filename, ls_null, ls_dir, 3)
   end if
end if


// Define ShellExcecute as Local External Function 
// somewhere in your application or as Global External Function:
Function Long ShellExecute (Long hWnd, String lpOperation, String lpFile, String lpParameters, String lpDirectory, Long nShowCmd) Library "shell32.dll" Alias For "ShellExecuteA"
```

It isn't exactly what you were looking for but it works!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You got me curious about this one when you said that the feature is available in PB12.5 as I didn't think it was possible.

After some trial and error I learned that the new datawindow feature is only available in some of the PowerBuilder 12.5 Targets.  In short, the feature is limited to the newly designed WPF datawindow. The image below shows how the new feature looks. You can expand each buffer section to view rows in that buffer and you can expand a row to view all the columns for that row.

[image]

I created a blog post that shows an examples of using the new feature including showing data in the primary and filter buffers.  The blog article can be found via this link: The [New PowerBuilder 12.5.NET DataWindow Buffer Debugging Feature](http://www.displacedguy.com/tech/powerbuilder-12-5-net-datawindow-buffer-view-edit-in-debugger).